# How can an aggregation be greater than the total number of hits?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have records of the type

```
 {
   "_index": "constant",
   "_type": "host",
   "_id": "AU7TX249tNLhGJRMfUXb",
   "_score": 1,
   "_source": {
               "private": true,
               "host-ip": "172.22.69.64",
               }
}
```

If I look for aggregates of `private` and `host-ip` via

```
POST constant/host/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "size": 0,
   "aggs":{
       "test":{
           "cardinality":{
               "field": "host-ip"
           }
       },
      "test2":{
            "cardinality":{
                "field": "private"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I get as a result

```
{
   "took": 7,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 7730,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "test": {
         "value": 7860
      },
      "test2": {
         "value": 2
      }
   }
}
```

My understanding of the result above is the following:

- there is a total of 7730 documents of type `host` in the index `constant`
- there are two different values for `private` (this is expected)

What I do not understand is how it is possible to have 7860 distinct values of `host-ip` when the total number of documents in the index is 7730?

Is my understanding of `total` in `hits` correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) is not exact. As the doc says:

> A single-value metrics aggregation that calculates an approximate count of distinct values

So, that's the reason behind the greater number.

You can play with the option `precision_threshold` to make results more accurate, but it will consume more resources.

Comment: Thank you. I got that search body form someone and did not (sadly) RTFM as I was not expecting the problem to be on that side (I read about `total` in `hits`). The docs you point to have a complete coverage of that point, with even a big header called [Counts are approximate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_counts_are_approximate)